# Bind radio selection and set to Model in csharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I have a for each statement that displays boostrap cards that contains delivery address information from the Model "DeliveryPoints".

Each "delivery point" contains deliveryPoint.felnam, deliveryPoint.feladr1, deliveryPoint.feladr2, deliveryPoint.feladr3 and deliveryPoint.felpcd

- deliveryPoint.felnam = delivery address name
- deliveryPoint.feladr1 = delivery address line 1
- deliveryPoint.feladr2 = delivery address line 2
- deliveryPoint.feladr3 = delivery address line 3
- deliveryPoint.felpcd = delivery address postcode

Each "delivery point" has a radio selection that contains a unique id (count++...).

If the user selects example bootstrap card number 2 which would have a radio selection with **e.g. id="rad_2"** I need it to update the **Model.DeliverPoint** , which contains deliverPoint.felnam, deliverPoint.feladr1, deliverPoint.feladr2, deliverPoint.feladr3 and deliverPoint.felpcd too their chosen selection (deliveryPoint.felnam and so on....).

What is the best way to achieve this?

**Deliver Point (which displays the chosen address)**

```
<h4 class="pt-4">Delivery Point</h4>

                    <div class="delivery-card" style="margin-top: 1.5rem;">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.DeliverPoint)
                        <div class="delivery-card__content">
                            <div class="delivery-card__content-top">
                                <div class="delivery-card_img">
                                    <i class="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="delivery-card_content-mid">
                                <h4>@Model.DeliverPoint.Felnam</h4>
                                <p class="mb-0">@Model.DeliverPoint.Feladr1, @Model.DeliverPoint.Feladr2, @Model.DeliverPoint.Feladr3, @Model.DeliverPoint.Felpcd</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="delivery-card__footer">
                            <p data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#DeliveryModalXX" style="color: #3282f9!important;" class="mb-1 mt-1">Change delivery point...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Delivery Points (which displays cards for the user to chosen from as their delivery address)**

```
<div class="row">
                        @{int count = 0;}
                        @foreach (Deladd_Data deliveryPoint in Model.DeliveryPoints)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <div class="form-check customfc pe-4" style="padding-left:0;">
                                    <div class="delivery-card" style="margin-top: 1.5rem;">
                                        <div class="delivery-card__content">
                                            <div class="delivery-card__content-top">
                                                <div class="delivery-card_img">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal" style="font-size: 2rem;"></i>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="delivery-card_content-mid">
                                                <h4>@deliveryPoint.Felnam</h4>
                                                <p class="mb-0">@($"{deliveryPoint.Feladr1}{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(deliveryPoint.Feladr2) ? "" : $", {deliveryPoint.Feladr2}")}{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(deliveryPoint.Feladr3) ? "" : $", {deliveryPoint.Feladr3}")}{(string.IsNullOrEmpty(deliveryPoint.Felpcd) ? "" : $", {deliveryPoint.Felpcd}")}")</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="delivery-card__footer">
                                            <div style="padding-left: 25px;">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id='@($"rad_{count}")'>
                                                @{count++;}
                                                <label class="form-check-label">Deliver to this address</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
```